# Can I add a prefix or suffix to the keys of a TypeScript interface/type which is programmatically generated?

Tags: typescript, typing

I am wondering, if it is possible to to add a prefix or suffix to a TypeScript type which uses an array of strings as its keys.

```
type First = {
  one: string
  two: string
}

type Second = keyof First 

type Third = {
  [S in Second]: any
}
```

With this approach Third accepts the attributes `one` & `two` with any type. Which is amazing, as I only need to change the first type in order to have the others also updated.

Now I want a fourth type which is exactly the same as `Third` but I want to add a prefix to the keys. Like a dollar sign or something.

Desired result:

```
type Fourth = {
  $one: any
  $two: any
}
```

I could just hard code it but than I would have to adjust the Fourth type if the First type has been changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TS 4.1 [has support for easy key remapping](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#key-remapping-mapped-types) using template literal types:

```
type First = {
  one: string
  two: string
}

type Fourth = {
    [K in keyof First as `$${K}`]: any
}
```

If you wanted to use the original type associated with each key instead of `any` (if you're using TS, you should want to avoid `any` when possible, after all!), replace

```
: any
```

with

```
: First[K]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just updated to version 4.1. Also thanks for the second tip. It's very helpful. The any was just for the example. In my code I need to refer to a new type but it is definitely  worth knowing how to map the original type. 